# SQL JOIN - comments with reactions (2 tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make one SQL command.
From table with comments i'll get comment id, then
with this ID I need to get count of reactions with the same comment ID and user's names.

So for example I have this 2 tables:

Comments:

| ID | Comm_text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Example text |
| 2 | Another example |

and Reactions:

| ID | comm_id | usr | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Peter | another |
| 2 | 1 | John | collon |
| 3 | 1 | Dog | cuz |
| 4 | 2 | Cat | why not |

I need to get this:

| ID | Comm_text | Reactions_Count | Users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Example text | 3 | Peter, John, Dog |
| 2 | Another example | 1 | Cat |

I tried this:

```
SELECT k.id, k.comm, COUNT(r.id) as reactions, r.usr
FROM `comms` k
  INNER JOIN `reactions` r ON r.id=k.id
```

It's just one row with one comment and count of all rows in reaction table.

Thanks.

Comment: and what is the output of your query?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask. better question.

Comment: @gp_sflover One row with first comment and count of all rows in Reaction table.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, group_concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query that makes the same output:

```
select comments.id as ID , comments.Comm_text as Comm_text , 
(select count(id) from Reactions where comm_id = comments.id) as Reactions_Count ,
(select coalesce(GROUP_CONCAT(usr ORDER BY usr DESC) , '') from Reactions WHERE comm_id = comments.id) as Users

from comments group by comments.id
```

You should use `group by` to group the comments and have just one row then use query to count and gather the data, based on each row of the group.

The `GROUP_CONCAT` attach the output with `,` and the `coalesce` set the output to a given string if the output was empty.

Read more about:

- [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)
- [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp)
- [subquery](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php)

Answer (score 0):

According to the names that u set in the example, this will work. Just fix the table names for your database structure.

```
SELECT `Comments`.`ID`, `Comments`.`Comm_text`, count(`Reactions`.`comm_id`) as react, `Reactions`.`usr`
FROM `Comments`
INNER JOIN `Reactions`
ON `Comments`.`ID`=`Reactions`.`comm_id`
GROUP BY `Reactions`.`comm_id`
```